# Swift 'Must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Tags: ios, swift, ios9.2

I have some basic code, trying to load a UITableView with some cells. I had set cell's ID in Storyboard,and create a swift file and xib for cell named "DemoListCell". I keep getting this error, although i don't use storyboards in my project.
Any ideas?     Thanks for all of you .

```
import UIKit
```

// MARK:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource {
let cellId = "DemoListID"
let TopTableView = UITableView()
let PageTableView  = UITableView()
let PageScrollView = UIScrollView()
var CellsIdentifier:String = ""
var NumbersofTab:CGFloat = 4
var Number:CGFloat = 4
var Size:CGFloat = 0
var OldPoint:CGFloat = 0
var NewPoint:CGFloat = 0{
    didSet{
        TopTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

// MARK: - ViewDidLoad and init()
override func viewDidLoad() {


    let TopWidth = self.view.frame.size.width
    Size = TopWidth
    let TopHeight:CGFloat = 50
    let TopY = 0 - (TopWidth - TopHeight)/2
    let TopX = 0 + (TopWidth - TopHeight)/2
    let PageY = TopHeight
    let PageHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - TopHeight

    //TopTableView
    TopTableView.frame = CGRectMake(TopX, TopY, TopHeight,TopWidth)
    TopTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI/2))
    TopTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    TopTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    TopTableView.dataSource = self
    TopTableView.delegate = self

    //PageTableView


    PageTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, TopWidth,PageHeight)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "DemoListCell", bundle: nil) //Cell's Name
    self.PageTableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    PageTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    //PageScrollView
    PageScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, PageY, TopWidth,PageHeight)
    PageScrollView.delegate = self
    PageScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: TopWidth * NumbersofTab, height: PageScrollView.frame.height)
    PageScrollView.pagingEnabled = true
    PageScrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
    PageScrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false




    //addSubview
    self.view.addSubview(TopTableView)

    PageScrollView.addSubview(PageTableView)

    self.view.addSubview(PageScrollView)

}
```

}

// MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    OldPoint = PageScrollView.contentOffset.x

}
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    NewPoint = PageScrollView.contentOffset.x
    print("\( NewPoint)")
}
```

}
// MARK: - UITableViewDalegate

```
extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate{

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DemoListCell
    if tableView.isEqual(TopTableView){
    var cell:TopTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cd") as? TopTableViewCell
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = TopTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cd")
        switch indexPath.row{
        case 0:
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        case 1:
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        case 2:
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        case 3:
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        default:
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        }
    }

    cell.TabTitle.text = "\(Int(NewPoint / Size))"
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let RowNumber:Int = 1
    switch RowNumber{
    default: return Int(NumbersofTab)
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let NumberofPages = Size / NumbersofTab
    return NumberofPages
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { () -> Void in
        let Pages = self.Size * CGFloat(indexPath.row)
        self.PageScrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: Pages, y: 0)
        self.TopTableView.reloadData()
        self.NewPoint = self.PageScrollView.contentOffset.x
    }
}
}
```

and this is "CellId" cell's Code:

```
class DemoListCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var cellImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var cellLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellIcon: UIImageView!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.cellImg.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.cellImg.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
    self.cellImg.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    self.cellImg.image = UIImage(named: "avatar.jpg")// Initialization code
    self.cellIcon.image = UIImage(named: "Next")
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

and there is "Cd" cell's Code:

```
class TopTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var TabTitle = UILabel()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    TabTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    TabTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
    TabTitle.numberOfLines = 1
    TabTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    TabTitle.textColor = UIColor(red: 130/255, green: 137/255, blue: 141/255, alpha: 1.0)
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.TabTitle)
    // 130 137 141
    self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 100, bottom: 0, right: -100)

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {

    let marginX = CGFloat(0.0)
    let marginY = CGFloat(0.0)
    let width = CGFloat(30)
    let height = self.contentView.frame.size.width
    self.TabTitle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI/2))

    self.TabTitle.frame = CGRectMake(marginX, marginY, width, height)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you register a nib with `registerNib`, you pass in a reuse identifier (second parameter). That identifier needs to be used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. However, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` uses `"cd"` as the reuse identifier, not `cellId`, the one you registered the nib with. To fix this, change the two reuse identifier strings in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
var cell:TopTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as? TopTableViewCell
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = TopTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
```

**Edit**

My mistake, I did not see the other dequeue at the top of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. However, I only saw one nib registered in `viewDidLoad`, so that means `TopTableViewCell` was never registered with identifier `"cd"`.

Comment: i have got another cell with identifier "cd". so, there are two Tableview in project. one is toptableview another one is pagetableview. I want use "cd" cell in toptableview and use "cellId" in pagetableview.

Comment: @lyq11 I didn't see that, but that means that `TopTableViewCell` is never registered. You have to register `TopTableViewCell` also.

Comment: @lyq11 Even if TopTableViewCell is not related to a xib, you still have to register it in the view controller.

Comment: @lyq11 You have to register `TopTableViewCell` with `TopTableView` in order for this to work, which is likely the reason for the crash. Just try registering it and then reply again if it doesn't work.